# How to pass class as generics?

Tags: java, android, generics

I am new to java generics and below is the code that has created a confusion for me to pass generics class as an argument to the method.
I have created an android project where i have used Volley library to handle server calls.Below is the code

Advanced Connection Util : this class returns the JacksonRequest object

```
public class AdvancedConnectionUtil<T> {

private String requestType;
private ServerListener listener;

public AdvancedConnectionUtil(String requestType , ServerListener<T> listener){

    this.listener = listener;
    this.requestType = requestType;
}

public JacksonRequest getRequest(){

             //This gives compile error while while passing DataList.class in the argument
            return new JacksonRequest<T>(Request.Method.GET, HttpRequestConstant.JACKSON_FETCH, null ,DataList.class, new Response.Listener<T>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(T response) {
                    listener.onDataReceived(response);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    listener.onErrorReceived(error.getMessage());
                }
            });
    }


public interface ServerListener<T> {

    public void onDataReceived(T data);

    public void onErrorReceived(String errorMsg);

}

}
```

Custom JacksonRequest class : this class handles the server call and the success call backs

```
public class JacksonRequest<T> extends JsonRequest<T> {

private Class<T> responseType;

/**
 * Creates a new request.
 *  @param method        the HTTP method to use
 * @param url           URL to fetch the JSON from
 * @param requestData   A {@link Object} to post and convert into json as the request. Null is allowed and indicates no parameters will be posted along with request.
 * @param responseType
 * @param listener      Listener to receive the JSON response
 * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors.
 */
public JacksonRequest(int method, String url, Object requestData, Class<T> responseType, Response.Listener<T> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, (requestData == null) ? null : Mapper.string(requestData), listener, errorListener);
    this.responseType = responseType;
}


@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return super.getHeaders();
}

@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

    try {
        String json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(Mapper.objectOrThrow(json, responseType), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}
```

}

Here is My activity class that creates a request and pass it to other method to make a server call

```
public class CustomJacksonRequestActivity extends SuperActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    showProgressBar();

  JacksonRequest jacksonRequest = new AdvancedConnectionUtil<DataList>(null, httpListener).getRequest();

    //This commented code works fine when i create a request this way
   /* JacksonRequest<DataList> jacksonRequest = new JacksonRequest<DataList>(Request.Method.GET, HttpRequestConstant.JACKSON_FETCH, null, DataList.class, new Response.Listener<DataList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(DataList response) {
            hideProgressBar();
            Log.e("ANSH", "onResponse : " + response.getPicture());
           // fillListWithIndex(response);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            hideProgressBar();
            Log.e("ANSH", "onErrorResponse : " + error.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });*/

    onExecute(jacksonRequest);
}

@Override
protected void internetAvailable() {

}


@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    super.setTitle("CustomJacksonActivity");
}
 private AdvancedConnectionUtil.ServerListener  httpListener = new AdvancedConnectionUtil.ServerListener<DataList>() {
    @Override
    public void onDataReceived(DataList data) {
        Log.e("ANSH", "onResponse : " + data.getPicture());
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorReceived(String errorMsg) {
        Log.e("ANSH", "onResponse : " + errorMsg);
    }
};
```

Now the problem is i am not able to pass DataList.class(This is the response model class) as a parameter in the constructor of JacksonRequest Class inside the getRequest method of AdvancedConnectionUtil class though i am able to do that when i was creating the request object in the activity(see the commented code in the activity).
How can i pass the DataList.class to the constructor of JacsonRequest?

The updated code is in git hub now 
[github link to the project](https://github.com/youranshul/LearningVolley)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little confusing (you could do with a simpler example), but I'll give it a shot...

The `JacksonRequest` class takes one *generic type parameter* `<T>` and the type of 4th constructor parameter references this type: `, Class<T> responseType,`. That means that when an instance of `JacksonRequest` is instantiated (with T being a real type), the 4th parameter passed must guarantee to be of type `T.class`.

When you call the constructor...

```
return new JacksonRequest<T>(Request.Method.GET, blah, null ,DataList.class, ...
```

... you are calling it with a *generic type argument* `<T>`. The compiler must always be able to match generic type arguments with generic type parameters, but with the 4th parameter you are asking it to match `T` with `DataClass`. Since the compiler does not know what `T` is (or more precisely, it cannot guarantee that when it is instantiated, `T` will actually be `DataClass`), it gives an error.

Generally speaking, you cannot mix generic type parameters and real type values - you must consistently choose one or the other. There are options which allow you to specify that a generic type parameter will derive from a class or implement an interface (`<T super DataClass>` or `<T extends DataClass>`, but it's a bit much to explain here.

Comment: Your answer makes sense to me.But What is the way to do that. My only motive  from the AdvancedConnectionUtil class is to create request object and give it back to Activity class.Now what i can do to pass the response class(i.e, DataList.class) to the JacksonRequest constructor?Any idea ?

Comment: What happens if you pass T.class instead of DataList.class as the 4th parameter?

Comment: I tried T.class but it draws red line and says "Can not select from a type variable"

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that :
Your `JacksonRequest<T>` is declared to take a `listener` that ***must be*** parameterized on the same type as your `responseType`

However with your `AdvancedConnectionUtil<T>.getRequest(...)`, there is no guarantee that the JacksonRequest created will meet the above requirement. Because you can always write code like:

```
new AdvancedConnectionUtil<String> (null, httpListener).getRequest();
```

So the parameter you passed into the constructor of `JacksonRequest` will be a `DataList.class` (of type `Class<DataList>`) and a `listener` of type `Listener<String>`

Sadly there is no way to do `T.class` in Java, although that indeed feels like what you need. Usually in such cases we will declare the AdvancedConnectionUtil as:

```
class AdvancedConnectionUtil<T> {
  private final Class<T> responseType;
  private final ServerListener<T> serverListener;
  private final String requestType;

  public AdvancedConnectionUtil (String requestType , Class<T> responseType, ServerListener<T> listener) {
    this.requestType = requestType;
    this.responseType = responseType;
    this.serverListener = listener;
  }

  public JacksonRequest<T> getRequest(){
      return new JacksonRequest<T>(0, "", null ,responseType, new Response.Listener<T>(){
      ...        
      }
  }
```

You need pass your responseType of `Class<T>` into `AdvancedConnectionUtil` and keep it as a member field. This way the `AdvancedConnectionUtil` instance, when created, is strictly limited to provide `JacksonRequest` bounded to a specific response type.

You could in theory declare your getRequest method as `getRequest(Class<T> responseType)`. But your AdvancedConnectionUtil does not seem to gain anything from that

Comment: yeah at last i can do this :( Thanks anyway